# Allow the [gospel] tag

Tags: feature-request, tags

Currently the [gospel](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gospel) is refused because it is already covered by [gospels](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gospels). But the two, while very related, are not the same. [gospels](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gospels) covers the four accounts of the life of Christ. [gospel](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gospel) refers to the *message* of Christianity, not the books that talk about it.

Mark 16:15 says to "go into all the world and preach the gospel"

Whether we're debating about what the gospel *is*, talking about Person X's understanding of it, or have a question related to it, we need a tag for it!

So please, let's allow [gospel](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gospel)!

[image]

Comment: I just looked over the tag synonyms, and there doesn't appear to be anything that associates "gospel" with "gospels".

Comment: @MasonWheeler one second i'll screenshot my error message

Comment: All right.  I agree with your premise, BTW.  If I can't find a way to resolve it I'll take it to the SE team.

Comment: @MasonWheeler pic added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've added a [gospel](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gospel) tag.  Try asking your question now.

Comment: poifect! thank ye! :)

Comment: @DoubtingThomas. I find your use of singular *ye* disturbing. (This is perhaps because I come from one of the few parts of the world where plural *ye* is still common.)

Comment: @TRiG the correct term would be "thee"? I always mix up which antiquated "you" is which.

Comment: @DoubtingThomas. Well of course *thou* / *thee* is singular, and familar, while *you* / *ye* is plural or formal. The informal, friendly form *thou* is used for family members and for God (and is retained there, so that in modern English it is often seen as more formal). The plural form is also the polite form, and gradually spread, ousting the singular form.

Comment: However, the subject form (*you*) also ousted the object form (*ye*), and in some dialects *ye* remains as a plural form (serving for both subject and object, just as *you* does). Other dialects use *youse* (Scotland, Northern Ireland, Dublin), or *y'all* (Southern USA). But these too gradually become singular. As the treadmill progresses, some have even started using *all y'all* for the plural meaning.

Comment: @TRiG ha, thanks! and LOL at "all y'all", i hear that sometimes (i'm in Atlanta) lol

Comment: @DoubtingThomas. We'll, it seems to be a thing in English that plural *you* gradually becomes singular and then you need a replacement. Plurals over time: *you*, *y'all*, *all y'all*. And when eventually *all y'all* becomes singular, what will be its replacement?